# Why can I not expand the container?

Tags: javascript

I use css to expand/collapse containers (ExpandableBoxContainer) within a parent container (SnippetContainer). There is a button in each expandable container for copying the code put in readonly textarea with this code (#248 - #263):

```
/* Highlight - Copy to Clipboard */
<script>
  document.getElementById("SnippetContainer").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  let tgt = e.target.closest("input");
  if (tgt && tgt.matches(".copyBtn")) {
    const textarea = tgt.nextElementSibling;
    textarea.select();
    tgt.value = 'COPIED. Paste in SOURCE view!!!';
    document.execCommand('copy')
  } 
  else 
    tgt = e.target.closest("textarea");

  if (tgt.matches("[name=code]")) tgt.select()

})

</script>
```

The page structure is about like this:

```
<div id="SnippetContainer">
    <div class="ExpandableBoxContainer">
        <input...>
        <textarea>
            ...code snippet...
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="ExpandableBoxContainer">
        <input...>
        <textarea>
            ...code snippet...
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

On expanding the CodeBoxContainer, the console returns:
[image]

I can't find the reason and any fix to it.

Comment: Run your script after `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: `if (tgt.matches("[name=code]"))` is disconnected from the `if`–`else` before. `tgt` may indeed be `null` at this point. Did you mean `else { tgt = e.target.closest("textarea"); if(tgt.matches("[name=code]")){ tgt.select(); } }`?

Comment: @Dai If that was the issue the error would’ve been _“Cannot read property `addEventListener` of `null`”_ and be unrelated to `tgt`.

Comment: What do you expect `closest` is doing? And why it should find an `input` element?

Comment: `e.target.closest("input")` will only ever return a DOM element if you clicked inside an `<input>` element. Otherwise it will always get you `null`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon aaah, whoops!

Comment: As these numerous comments illustrate already: it _always_ makes sense to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - instead of "The page structure is about like this".

Answer (score 1):

You get the error at `if (tgt.matches("[name=code]")) tgt.select()` if `tgn` is `null`.

`tgn` is `null` if you click either at `SnippetContainer` or a descendant of it that is neither `input` nor `textarea`.

You would need to change `if (tgt.matches("[name=code]")) tgt.select()` to `if (tgt && tgt.matches("[name=code]")) tgt.select()` to make the error vanish.

But it is not fully clear if the logic that you have in your code is really correct, it at least looks highly suspicious.

Comment: Thaks a ot. That't it. The whole thing had worked before. It did what it was expected to do, just te console had reported this error. Now it reports anything.
DEMO: https://cmsimple.sk/tests/snippets